# Check if object from one array is included inside another array of objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm

We have 2 arrays

```
const arr1 = [{color: 'red', shape: 'square'}, {color: 'blue', shape: 'circle'}, {color: 'green', shape: 'square}]
const arr2 = [{color: 'red', shape: 'circle'}, {color: 'blue', shape: 'circle'}]
```

I want to check if at least one item from arr2 is included inside of arr1 (if yes return bool value). So far i tried `arr2.some(item => arr1.includes(item))` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array `includes()` matches the object using reference equality, it does not deep compare item object's properties. So, you also need an object matcher.

```js
const overlap = arr1.some(i1 => arr2.some(i2 => matchObj(i1,i2)));
```

and you will have to write an implementation of `matchObj(obj1, obj2)`.

You can also use lodash's [`isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) or [`intersecttionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#intersectionWith) method:

```js
const arr1 = [{color: 'red', shape: 'square'}, {color: 'blue', shape: 'circle'}, {color: 'green', shape: 'square'}];
const arr2 = [{color: 'red', shape: 'circle'}, {color: 'blue', shape: 'circle'}];

// check for overlap
const hasCommon = _.some(arr1, i1 => _.some(arr2, i2 => _.isEqual(i1, i2)));
console.log('hasCommon:', hasCommon);

// get common items
const commonItems = _.intersectionWith(arr1, arr2, _.isEqual);
console.log('commonItems:', commonItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code arr2.some(item => arr1.find(e=>JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(item))

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.includes checks if it is equal so it is useful for primitive values. To check if it deep equal (for arrays and objects) you can use find method. So correct solution would be:

```
arr2.some(item => arr1.find(e=>e.color==item.color&&e.shape==item.shape))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array of object is small, not too big. You can use JSON.stringify too check.

```
const arr1_str = JSON.stringify(arr1);
arr2.some(item2 => arr1_str.includes(JSON.stringify(item2)));
```

```js
const arr1 = [{color: 'red', shape: 'square'}, {color: 'blue', shape: 'circle'}, {color: 'green', shape: 'square'}];
const arr2 = [{color: 'red', shape: 'circle'}, {color: 'blue', shape: 'circle'}];

const arr1_str = JSON.stringify(arr1);
console.log(arr2.some(item2 => arr1_str.includes(JSON.stringify(item2))));
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote I missclicked but from top of my head this will not work every time as objects are not in order